# Error when trying to add custom attribute programmatically

Tags: magento-2.1, product, custom-attributes, setup, installdata

I got this error when I try to create a custom attribute for products:

```
The configuration parameter "formElement" is a required for "instruction" field.
```

> InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
private $eavSetupFactory;

public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'instruction',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Installation Manual',
            'input' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable,grouped',
            'group'=> 'General'
        ]
    );
}
}
```

I'm using **magento 2.1.8**.
I read that I have to change the `frontend_input` in the `eav_attribute` table in the database, but I don't want to add it manually, and I don't know what do I have to add there.

How can I add this attribute at the setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes on admin... Stores > Attributes > Products